# Plotting 2D points without line in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have some 2D points and I want to plot them in MATLAB such that every point has a different color and specifier. I have used `plot` function but it creates line whatever you give. I want to draw these points as discrete points only. How can I do that? Here is what I am trying to achieve in the simplest form (I used TikZ below):

[image]

**UPDATE:**
Thank you for your comments and answers, I have the following code right now:

```
x = [  0.56, 0.4526, -0.4324, 0.2749, -0.2993, 0.3404, 0.1959, 0.3363, -0.1706];
y = [0.1999, 0.3939,  0.1999, 0.4414,  0.2000, 0.3931, 0.1999, 0.3966,  0.4056];

figure
plot(x(1),y(1),'rx')
hold on
plot(x(2),y(2),'*','Color','[0 0.9 0]')
hold on
plot(x(3),y(3),'*','Color','[0 0.5 0]')
hold on
plot(x(4),y(4),'o','Color','[0.47 0.52 0.8]','MarkerFaceColor','[0.47 0.52 0.8]')
hold on
plot(x(5),y(5),'o','Color','[0.05 0.28 0.63]','MarkerFaceColor','[0.05 0.28 0.63]')
hold on
plot(x(6),y(6),'s','Color','[1 0.71 0.30]','MarkerFaceColor','[1 0.71 0.30]')
hold on
plot(x(7),y(7),'s','Color','[0.9 0.32 0]','MarkerFaceColor','[0.9 0.32 0]')
%plot(x(7),y(7),'s','Color','[1 0 0.5]','MarkerFaceColor','[1 0 0.5]')
hold on
plot(x(8),y(8),'d','Color','[0.67 0.28 0.73]','MarkerFaceColor','[0.73 0.40 0.78]')
%plot(x(8),y(8),'d','Color','[0.67 0.28 0.73]','MarkerFaceColor','[0.67 0.28 0.73]')
hold on
plot(x(9),y(9),'d','Color','[0.29 0.08 0.55]','MarkerFaceColor','[0.29 0.08 0.55]')
xlabel('X')
ylabel('Y')
h = legend('(^1X,^1Y)','(^2X_1,^2Y_1)','(^2X_2,^2Y_2)','(^3X_1,^3Y_1)','(^3X_2,^3Y_2)','(^4X_1,^4Y_1)','(^4X_2,^4Y_2)','(^5X_1,^5Y_1)','(^5X_2,^5Y_2)');
set(h,'Location','best')
grid
```

I can now draw the points as dots with different colors and specifiers although this way may not be the best way.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [`scatter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply specify the LineSpec option

http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#inputarg_LineSpec

To obtain your example:

```
plot(xdata, ydata, '.')
```

Comment: You can use ANY line plot and use `'linestyle','none'` option to remove lines.